# Can Windows CE (.NET CF 1.0) apps access web services?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, compact-framework, windows-ce

We are planning on replacing a legacy "server" app (a Windows form app with, although it does not really need it, a GUI representation (showing status messages)) with a simplified service of some sort. The server/service responds to requests for data and sends said data. Will a legacy (.NET CF 1.0) app, which cannot be updated to a newer technology (because the handheld devices on which they run don't have room for the more recent/larger .NET Compact Framework runtime) be able to access "newfangled" services such as an asp.net RESTful web service? If not, what are some other options? Or, if there are better options even with that being feasible, what might y'all suggest?

Comment: How about a web application instead i.e. with windows-ce accessing a website?

Comment: Okay; would limitations would there be for a .NET 1.1 app that way - could it use SignalR, for instance?

Comment: Are you restricted to .net 1.1 on the server or on the windows-ce device?

Comment: The Windows CE device.

Comment: I'd go for a web application instead, therefore all the Windows CE device needs is a web browser (albeit an old one), therefore the logic can all be server-side. Though of course there is a lot more to think about when web app vs client app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the older .Net "Service references" don't understand newer formats/protocols.

But, at the end of the day, it's all just a bunch of auto-generated code mapping "objects" to XML.

SUGGESTION:

Just parse the XML directly.

If in doubt, play with your target service using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)

Unless you've got a *really* complicated schema, that's probably the easiest to program - and most memory efficient - solution.

IMHO...